# Custom GUI design in linux

Tags: linux, user-interface

I was wondering if it has some manner to design more beautiful, personalized GUIs. All apps I've seen so far are Gtk based, which have the "linux face". It's not ugly, but what if I want my own design into my app?
Has linux a framework such a Windows Presentation Foundation?

Comment: Did you look at Qt library and Qt-designer?

Comment: Qt is used by KDE desktop, its quite flexible and you can create beautiful GUI using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try QT Framework. With the advent of Ubuntu 12.04 -- they are shifting from GTK and Gnome based application to QT based GUI's. QT has more beautiful and personalized GUI's.

http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

The main GUI frameworks are Qt and GTK+. If you don't like the looks of GTK+ programs it is probably easier to define a custom GTK+ theme than to write a new program from scratch. You can also define custom widgets which looks and works exactly as you want them to. There is also a more low-level (and cross platform) framework called SDL. There you will have to do everything from scratch. It basically only provides functions to draw to the screen and read keyboard and mouse events. But you can create a program which looks exactly the way you want with SDL. Because of that, and because it is fast, SDL is often used for games.

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets is another great cross-platform framework.